# Enter button on android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, multiline

I have an `editText` which allows multiline text. when the editText is focused and keyboard is shown. it shows the enter button on keyboard as shown in the attached image.

[image]

But when i open the hangouts app. it shows keyboard with some other button instead of enter button.

[image]

How i can show similar button in my app. Also is it possible to show some custom button on keyboard?

if someone can give some reading material related to keyboards it will be really helpful as i have very little knowledge about keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: thanks for the link. can i achive this with the existing imeoptions?